# Pandas COUNTIF per dataframe column value

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have this excel formula:

```
=IF(L2="","",IF(COUNTIF($L$1:L2,L2)=1,"1YR",IF(COUNTIF($L$1:L2,L2)=2,"3YR","5YR")))
```

which am translating into software with pandas. This `countif` is a tricky one, as only the previous cells above the current cell needs to be checked and counted if the value in the current cell occurs in it.

**current solutions:**

```
df['year'] = np.where(df['company_id'] is None, None,
                np.where(pd.cut(df['company_id'], df.loc[df['company_id']].index[0]).count() == 1, '1YR',
               np.where(pd.cut(df.company_id, df.loc[df['company_id']].index[0]).count() == 2, '3YR', '5YR')))
```

**desired output:**

```
company_id  year
48299       1YR
48752       1YR
48865       1YR
48299       3YR
49503       1YR
48299       5YR
49697       1YR
50267       1YR
50714       1YR
50714       3YR
51050       1YR
```

Using `pandas.cut` function, but i don't think this is the right way to go about this. Any help towards the right direction will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary:

```
d = {0:'1YR', 1:'3YR', 2: '5YR'}
df['new'] = df.groupby(['company_id']).cumcount().map(d)
print (df)
    company_id year  new
0        48299  1YR  1YR
1        48752  1YR  1YR
2        48865  1YR  1YR
3        48299  3YR  3YR
4        49503  1YR  1YR
5        48299  5YR  5YR
6        49697  1YR  1YR
7        50267  1YR  1YR
8        50714  1YR  1YR
9        50714  3YR  3YR
10       51050  1YR  1YR
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response and solution. it works!